# Smyfony2 Comparing Data with existing data from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I output a list of task based on the current user.

My Task Table looks like this:

```
ID | Task Title | User |
```

I also have a second table called "TaskDone"

There I store when a task is marked as "done" by a specific User. For example like this:

```
ID | Task ID | User ID |
 1 |    13   |    3    |
```

When I output now my list of task for User ID 3 , I get a list of all task assigned to User ID 3. But now I want to check if there is a task in the list, which has an entry in the table "TaskDone" with User ID = current User and Task ID = ID of the task from the output list.

My controller looks like this:

```
/**
@Route(
 *     path = "/taskmanager/user/{id}",
 *     name = "taskmanager"
 * )
 * @Template()
 */
public function taskManagerAction($id)
{

    $priorities = array(
        0 => array('name' => 'Hoch', 'class' => 'high' ),
        1 => array('name' => 'Normal', 'class' => 'normal' ),
        2 => array('name' => 'Niedrig', 'class' => 'low' )
    );

    $all_tasks = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Task')
        ->findAll();

    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:User')
        ->findAll();

    return array(
        'list_user' => $user,
        'list_open_tasks' => $all_tasks,
        'current_user' => $id,
        'priorities' => $priorities,
    );

}
```

My output of the task list looks like this:

```
{% for task in list_open_tasks if (task.user.id == current_user or task.user.id == "global") and task.taskPriority == priority.name %}

    {{ task.taskTitle }}
    # HERE I WANT TO CHECK IF THERE IS AN ENTRY IN TASKDONE TABLE FOR THIS TASK AND THIS USER

{% endfor %}
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this within your controller!

This code would give you out all entries as an array from the `TaskDone` Entity where the `user_id` is the same as the given `$id`.

```
$tasks_done = $this->getDoctrine() ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:TaskDone') ->findBy(array('user' => $id);
```

Save the results in an array like `$tasksDone` and return it to the TwigTemplate.

```
return array(
    'list_user' => $user,
    'list_open_tasks' => $all_tasks,
    'current_user' => $id,
    'priorities' => $priorities,
    'tasks_done' => $tasksDone
);
```

Then you just give them out like any other Twig Variable

Comment: You mean here? :
$all_tasks = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Task')
->findAll(); <---- HERE ???

Comment: Thank you, now I have an array with all done task ids from user X. But for output I need the data from the table "Task". 
So what i need is somethink like this:
Give me all data from table 'task' where ID and user ID exists in table "task_done"